# Why is my functional component's state undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a flashcard App, my flashcard component is as below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Flashcard.css'
import {
    Button,
} from '@material-ui/core';


function Flashcard({ data }) { 
    // // Get an initial card
    const [currentCard, setCurrentCard ] = useState(data[0]);
    // Create state to track whether the card has been flipped yet
    const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);
    
    // When the Flip button is clicked, we display the verso
    const handleFlipClick = () => {
        setFlipped(true);
    }

    const handleNextClick = () => {
        // Change the current active card
        setCurrentCard(data[1]);
        
        // Restore the 'flipped' state to indicate that the new active card hasn't been flipped yet
        setFlipped(false);
        
    }  

    // Get data needed from the server
    return ( 
    
        <div className="flashcard__container"> 
        {/* Card content goes here */}
            <div className="flashcard__content">
                <p>
                    { (flipped) ? currentCard.verso : currentCard.recto }
                </p>
            </div>


            <div className="flashcard__actions">
                {/* Display the flip button if the card hasn't been flipped yet */}
                
                {(!flipped) ? 
                        
                        <Button 
                                variant="contained" 
                                color="primary"
                                onClick={handleFlipClick}
                        >Flip</Button>
                :
                    <>

                    <Button onClick={handleNextClick} color='primary' variant='contained'>
                        Hard
                    </Button>

                    <Button onClick={handleNextClick} color='primary' variant='contained'>
                        Slightly difficult
                    </Button>

                    <Button onClick={handleNextClick} color='primary' variant='contained'>
                        Good
                    </Button>

                    <Button onClick={handleNextClick} color='primary' variant='contained'>
                        Easy
                    </Button>
                    </>
                }
                
            </div>
        </div>

        
    )
}

export default Flashcard
```

'data' is pass from another component, when I console log it in the Flashcard component, here is what I get:

```
[
  0: {id: "PynaJl43Jphl2xI8fWkn", reviewedOn: Array(2), recto: "To go", verso: "行く"}
  1: {id: "mSDdg5ATenvjBYojfy8N", verso: "こんにちは", recto: "Hi", reviewedOn: Array(2)
]
```

However, this line: `(flipped) ? currentCard.verso : currentCard.recto` gives me the following error message: "Type Error - Cannot read property 'recto' of undefined".
Indeed, when I try to console log 'currentCard', it says it is undefined. Why is that happening? I don't see any mistake in the way I initialized the state. Thank you!

Here is the parent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import FlashCard from './Flashcard';
import mockData from './mockData';
import { getParams, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { db } from './firebase';
import Header from './Header';

function Deck() {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [cards, setCards] = useState(); // Create a state to store the deck
    
    //  When the page is first loaded: Import the deck's card from the database
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection(`decks/${id}/cards`)
            // Return an array of cards
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                setCards(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
                    return {
                        id: doc.id,
                        ...doc.data()
                    }
                }))
            })
                     
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            {cards && <FlashCard data={cards} />}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Deck
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` is likely undefined when this component is first rendered. You can fix this in one of two ways.

1.) Add logic to the parent component so that `Flashcard` is not rendered until `data` is defined.

```js
{data && <Flashcard data={data} />}
```

2.) Add a `useEffect` that monitors for changes to `data` and updates state.

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
if(typeof currentCard === 'undefined'){
    setCurrentCard(data[0])
}
}, [data])
```

Comment: I did it but I still get the problem. I edited my post to show the parent component as well

Comment: In that case, I'll need to see a Codesandbox or something similar with minimum reproduction config.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-elion-7pxjw?file=/src/Deck.js:341-720
Here it is! I don't have the issue in sandbox. I've noticed that the problem appears when I retrieve data from Firestore. If I use local data it works.
The thing that I don't get is that my Firebase call is inside a useEffect() before the return. Shouldn't react get my data, then render the Flashcard component?
My call to firebase is commented in the sandbox.

Comment: It worked after doing: 
{(typeof(cards) === 'undefined') ? <p>Loading</p> : <FlashCard data={cards} />}.
Thank you!

Comment: It just means that db.collection is an async function so the results aren't immediately available. I'm glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are passing some faulty data into the props. Try my sample, it works:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
// import { FlashCard } from "./FlashCard";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";

function Flashcard({ data }) {
  // // Get an initial card
  // // Get an initial card
  const [currentCard, setCurrentCard] = useState(data[0]);
  // Create state to track whether the card has been flipped yet
  const [flipped, setFlipped] = useState(false);

  // When the Flip button is clicked, we display the verso
  const handleFlipClick = () => {
    setFlipped(true);
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    // Change the current active card
    setCurrentCard(data[1]);

    // Restore the 'flipped' state to indicate that the new active card hasn't been flipped yet
    setFlipped(false);
  };

  // Get data needed from the server
  return (
    <div className="flashcard__container">
      {/* Card content goes here */}
      <div className="flashcard__content">
        <p>{flipped ? currentCard.verso : currentCard.recto}</p>
      </div>

      <div className="flashcard__actions">
        {/* Display the flip button if the card hasn't been flipped yet */}

        {!flipped ? (
          <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleFlipClick}>
            Flip
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Button
              onClick={handleNextClick}
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Hard
            </Button>

            <Button
              onClick={handleNextClick}
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Slightly difficult
            </Button>

            <Button
              onClick={handleNextClick}
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Good
            </Button>

            <Button
              onClick={handleNextClick}
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
            >
              Easy
            </Button>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Flashcard
        data={[
          {
            id: "PynaJl43Jphl2xI8fWkn",
            reviewedOn: Array(2),
            recto: "To go",
            verso: "行く"
          },
          {
            id: "mSDdg5ATenvjBYojfy8N",
            verso: "こんにちは",
            recto: "Hi",
            reviewedOn: Array(2)
          }
        ]}
      ></Flashcard>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this in a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-snowflake-kysxn) and it worked just fine. My guess is you have an error on the props name when passing props to the Flashcard component?

It should be rendered as seen below since in Flashcard you are destructuring data from props:

```
<Flashcard data = {insertArrayHere} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using useEffect and adding data as a dependency. Then in useEffect check, if the data exists it should change the state. You can make it this way:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(data){
       setCurrentCard(data[0]);
   }
}, [data])
```

or you can check existing of this prop in the parent element, adn if it exists show it that time. You can implement it in this way:

```
{ data ? <Flashcard data={data} /> : null }
```